# programmatically retrieve email status using amazon ses in c#

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, status

I am using Amazon SES SDK for c#.net to send emails. I am also receiving the message id in response object.
Is there any way to programmatically retrieve the email status(bounced/complained/delivered) using these message id?

Comment: As SO is a site for helping with software programming problems, it's customary to provide a [mcve] in a question. This helps to assess what you have already tried and where you stand today. It also prevents those that answer to waste time on writing suggestions that may have already been tried.

Answer (score 1):

We can receive bounced/Complaint email details through API and process them programmatically using java code.
**Steps to be carried out to do so:**

1. Create Amazon Simple Notification Service topic, name it as
   ses-bounce-topic
2. Create Amazon Simple Queue Service queue, name it as
   ses-bounces-queue
3. Configure Amazon Simple Notification Service topic to publish
   notifications to queue
4. Configure Amazon Simple Email Service to publish bounce
   notifications using ses-bounces-topic to ses-bounces-queue
5. After completing this configurations we can simply read the bounced
   mails through SQS in JSON format.

   ```
       AmazonSQS sqs = new AmazonSQSClient(credentialsProvider);
   sqs.setRegion(region);

   ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest    = new ReceiveMessageRequest(amazonQueueUrl);   
   List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
   for (Message message : messages) {
   System.out.println("  Message");
   System.out.println("    MessageId:     " + message.getMessageId());
   System.out.println("    ReceiptHandle: " + message.getReceiptHandle());
   System.out.println("    MD5OfBody:     " + message.getMD5OfBody());
   System.out.println("    Body:          " + message.getBody().contains("emailAddress"));
    }
   ```